# Apache ErrorDocument 500

Tags: apache, virtualhost, errordocument

In my VirtualHost I setup default error pages.

Example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <Directory /var/www/html/>
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorDocument 403 /error_page/403.php
        ErrorDocument 404 /error_page/404.php
        ErrorDocument 500 /error_page/500.php
        ErrorDocument 503 /error_page/503.php
</VirtualHost>
```

Error 403 and 404 seems to work but error 500 doesn't.
As a test I require a php file that i know doesn't exists:

```
require ("unknown_file.php");
```

In Safari the page stays blank and in Chrome or Edge I get the default Error 500 page.
I can set display_errors in PHP to On but that i do not get the custom 500 page but the error message which I don't want in production.

What am I doing wrong?
I have restarted apache and PHP but that didn't make any difference.

Comment: Apache already handled the request to PHP, it's not going to discard PHP output to show its own page. The same happens with e.g. 404, if you send a Not Found status from PHP using `header()` you will not get the error page set there.

Comment: That means what I did is good but my error appears after apache handels it? I can catch the error in PHP and show the 500 there but where is the Error 500 rule in apache for than?

Answer (score 0):

Error 500 is for a (temporary?) server error.
If you want to simulate it, just put this in a php file (eg: test_error_500_page.php)

```
header('something', true, 500);
```

Now calling [www.yoursite.com/test_error_500_page.php](http://www.yoursite.com/test_error_500_page.php) you'll get the "/error_page/500.php" page contents

Comment: That works, I just wanted to know that if the server crashes it also works. Simulating now works but that is in PHP

Comment: If the server "crashes" it must works as espected, the defined error page in Apache will be displayed.
The "header" in the test page simulate a real 500 error, cause headers in php calls a "new conections" with that code to apache, which handles upon defined directives, if any

Comment: Okay, clear. I just see something wrong now. When I go to www.example.com/whatever I get my custom error page, for almost every URL that doesn't exist, except when I type .php after it, than I get the text File not found. With this row in the error log: AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown'

Comment: Sorry, cannot edit anymore...
You type a url in the browser, the browser sends the request to apache, which handles the requests and pass it to Php (or whatever, depending on apache config). Upon normal flow, php return a "200" header to apache along with other output. Apache then sends the php's output to the browser. If you send any other return code (headers) through php to apache, then Apache handles according

Comment: First of all try a restart of apache. If the error persists, check with apachectl configtest

Comment: apachectl configtest gives me this result: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.2.22. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Syntax OK

Comment: I think it depends on the website/vhost configuration.
May be you must have a .htaccess into the web root to catch nonexistent files
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /  
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]  
</IfModule>  `
Something like that, depending on your application. This is the standard .htaccess for wordpress

Comment: On the website i am testing i don't have any .htaccess file. So i think it should be something in the Apache configuration?